# customer acesss token never expiring JWT

Tags: customer, magento2.4, token, consumers

I have created a customer access token using the below method

```
// Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory  
$customerToken = $this->tokenModelFactory->create();  
$token = $customerToken->createCustomerToken($customerData->getId())->getToken();
```

For expiration time, I have set the configuration for 30 mins and tokens are generated according to that time

### [image]

[image]

Now using that token I am using the below method to load customer by token

```
//Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\Token as CustomerToken;  
$outhCustomer = $this->customerToken->loadByToken($token);
```

I also tried the below method to revoke the consumer token but the old token is still giving data.

```
//Magento\Integration\Api\CustomerTokenServiceInterface;
  $this->customerTokenService->revokeCustomerAccessToken($customerLoggedIn->getId());
```

The problem here is expiration time is not working even after token expiration has already passed on I can still get data from that old generated token.

Does anyone have any idea how to invalidate the consumer jwt token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I was using the wrong method to load the customer by JWT token.

The above methods work well to expire tokens and load the customer but `$this->customerToken->loadByToken($token)` will not validate if the JWT token is expired or not for that I have used the below method to load the customer.

```
// Magento\JwtUserToken\Model\Reader $jwtReader
$this->jwtReader->read($jwtToken)->getUserContext();
```

now customers are validating with proper validation if the JWT token is expired.